# Detect when child window needs redrawing

Tags: c++, winapi

Currently I am developing some custom controls and the problem I'm currently facing is that I don't know how to detect when my custom control needs redrawing.

I use `WM_PAINT` to draw everything, so I relly on `RedrawWindow()` function. However when my custom control moves outside drawing area and then comes back, it doesn't redraw. I tried catching `WM_NCPAINT` which works great, but then it sends `WM_PAINT` messages every time I move mouse inside parent window.

So my question is - how do I detect when to redraw child window after it comes back to drawing area?

Below is my code for `CALLBACK`:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinMsgHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, 
                               WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (uMsg)
        {
        case WM_CREATE:
            settings.TrackingEvent.hwndTrack = hWnd;
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            {
                PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
                switch (settings.CurrentState)
                    {
                    case cctrl_UNSELECTED_HOVER:
                        On_UnselectedHover(&hdc, &ps.rcPaint);
                        break;
                    case cctrl_UNSELECTED:
                        On_Unselected(&hdc, &ps.rcPaint);
                        break;
                    case cctrl_SELECTED_HOVER:
                        On_SelectedHover(&hdc, &ps.rcPaint);
                        break;
                    case cctrl_SELECTED:
                        On_Selected(&hdc, &ps.rcPaint);
                        break;
                    case cctrl_3STATE_HOVER:
                        On_IntermediateHover(&hdc, &ps.rcPaint);
                        break;
                    case cctrl_3STATE:
                        On_Intermediate(&hdc, &ps.rcPaint);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            }
            break;
        case WM_NCPAINT:
            RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_ERASE | RDW_FRAME
                        | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
            break;
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            On_MouseMove();
            break;
        case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
            On_MouseHover();
            break;
        case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
            On_MouseLeave();
            break;
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            On_LButtonDown();
            break;
        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            On_LButtonUp();
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            OnDestroy();
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `RedrawWindow` with `RDW_FRAME` will _trigger_ a `WM_NCPAINT` message. Can you say infinite loop?

Comment: Worked like a charm :), if you post it as an answer I will accept it.